# Calculate a user_liked column for posts if a user is logged in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-api

I'm using Rails API 5.0 in a blog application where users can log in and 'like' posts and comments similar to Facebook. When a user is logged in the client passes a token in the header of every request. This way my controller can see which user is making the request to the API.

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

if request.headers['Authorization']
  token_string = request.headers['Authorization']
  current_user = User.where(token: token_string).take
end
```

My models are set up so that users can have many posts, comments and likes. Likes of post and comments are kept in separate comment_likes and post_likes tables.

When a user is logged in I want them to be able to see all the posts and comments they have already 'liked' when viewing a list of posts or comments. I store this in an optional `user_liked` column. Initially I did this using a raw SQL query in my controller `index` method.

```
# app/controllers/posts_controller.rb

@posts = Post.joins("LEFT OUTER JOIN 
                      (SELECT * FROM post_likes 
                       WHERE post_likes.user_id = #{current_user.id}) AS pl
                       ON posts.id = pl.post_id")
.select("posts.*,CASE WHEN pl.user_id IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS user_liked")
```

However as I continue to work on the application I find that I want the `user_liked` column in every controller method when a user is logged in. It seems like it would be better to put it in the model.

Since the model doesn't have access to controller data, how can I create a model attribute that is dependent on `current_user`?

Answer (score 0):

Create a method on the model and call it from the controller and pass through the current user.

Ex:

```
@likes = Post.user_liked(current_user)

render json: @likes
```